# How to set E-Mail configuraion on android device programmatically

Tags: android, email

I want to create app on android and make it **config E-mail setting on android device programmatically** when it get setting data from server.

I have search around for android code example but I can't find any good example and I don't know where to start looking.

Can any one suggest where should I start looking?

Thank you

**Update** Sorry for an unclear question.

Comment: can u please elaborate your problem?

Comment: @Andrain Thank for quick reply.

I just want to config exchange account on android device programmatically. But I don't know how.

Can you provide me an example code or how Should start?

I just look around a bit more is it something to do with `AccountManager` class ?

Comment: yeah you should save user email address and password in app database or u r storing it with the help of `AccountManager`. Thus u can use it  whenever you want.

Answer (score 0):

I used this method to send email programmatically . you can use this. it will help you.

```
//send email
boolean sendMail(String from,String to)
{
        boolean isSend=false;

       Properties props = System.getProperties();
        String host = "smtp.gmail.com"; 

    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");   //enable for gmail
        props.put("mail.smtp.user", "abc@gmail.com");
        props.put("mail.smtp.password", "abc");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");   //gmail port address
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");

        Log.d("tag","props set");


        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props,null);
        Log.d("tag","session set");
        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
        Log.d("tag","message set");

        try {
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));

            InternetAddress add = new InternetAddress(to);

             message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, add);

            message.setSubject("hello");

           message.setText("hello world");

            Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");

            transport.connect(host,from, "hello world");
            transport.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());
            transport.close();
            isSend=true;
        }
        catch (AddressException ae) {
            ae.printStackTrace();
            isSend=false;
        }
        catch (MessagingException me) {
            me.printStackTrace();
            isSend=false;
        }

      return isSend;
}
```

Comment: Thank for your reply but what I need is programmatically config email setting on android not sending.

Comment: these are setting that is done programmatically Properties props = System.getProperties();
        String host = "smtp.gmail.com"; 

    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");   //enable for gmail
        props.put("mail.smtp.user", "abc@gmail.com");
        props.put("mail.smtp.password", "abc");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");   //gmail port address
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");